# Troubleshooting delayed job processing in a Ruby service class architecture

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello Stack Overflowers,

I'm working on a module structure in Ruby on Rails that uses HTTParty to interact with different external services. The architecture includes a base proxy service to handle HTTP requests via a proxy, and a base notifier class that is responsible for sending different types of notifications to these external services.

The actual service-specific classes inherit from the base proxy service and implement the notification methods.

```
require 'httparty'

module ExternalServiceModules
  class BaseProxy
    PROXY_NAME = 'proxy-name'.freeze
    PROXY_PASSWORD = 'proxy-password'.freeze
    PROXY_HOST = 'proxy-host'.freeze
    PROXY_PORT = 8888

    def get_with_proxy(endpoint)
      HTTParty.get(endpoint, default_options)
    end

    def post_with_proxy(endpoint, body)
      HTTParty.post(endpoint, default_options.merge(body: body.to_json))
    end

    def put_with_proxy(endpoint, body)
      HTTParty.put(endpoint, default_options.merge(body: body.to_json))
    end

    def delete_with_proxy(endpoint, body)
      HTTParty.delete(endpoint, default_options.merge(body: body.to_json))
    end

    private

    def default_options
      {
        http_proxyaddr: PROXY_HOST,
        http_proxyport: PROXY_PORT,
        http_proxyuser: PROXY_NAME,
        http_proxypass: PROXY_PASSWORD
      }
    end
  end

  class BaseNotifier
    def send_notification(item)
        return unless get_service_class(item)
        service_class = get_service_class(item)
        service_class.delay.send_notification(item.id.to_s)
    end

    private

    def get_service_class(item)
        service_code = item.service_form.service.code
        if ExternalServiceModules.const_defined?(service_code.capitalize)
            service_class = ExternalServiceModules.const_get(service_code.capitalize)
            return service_class.new
        else
            # capture error with a tracking tool
            return nil
        end
    end
  end

  class ServiceA < BaseProxy
    def send_notification(item_id)
      item = Item.find(item_id)
      puts json: {
        "reference": item.id,
        "field1": item.service_form.field1,
        "field2": item.service_form.field2,
      }
      put_with_proxy(ENV['SERVICE_A_HOST']+ENV['SERVICE_A_NOTIFY'])
    end
  end
end
```

The notifications to these external services should be processed as delayed jobs. In the base notifier class, I'm trying to accomplish this with service_specific_class.delay.method_name. However, these jobs don't seem to be executed as expected.

Although the jobs appear to be queued correctly, they are not processed. I have verified that my Delayed Job workers are running, and Delayed Job works correctly elsewhere in my application. This leads me to believe the issue could lie within my module structure.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions. What could potentially cause these jobs not to process? Could there be a more efficient way to structure these modules to work seamlessly with delayed jobs?

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide.